# Redis fails to start on OpenSuse Leap 42.1 after upgrade

Tags: service, opensuse, redis, chkconfig

I decided to upgrade a machine running 13.2 to the latest Leap 42.1. I started the process and it did the upgrade. After the reboot everything is working except for the redis server service. I can't start the redis service using:

```
# service redis start
```

The status is:

```
# service redis status
redis.target - Redis target allowing to start/stop all redis@.service instances at once
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.target; static)
   Active: active since Fri 2015-11-20 03:47:07 EET; 1s ago
```

Although it says it's "active", when I check if the process is running it's actually not:

```
# ps ax | grep -i redis
20892 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep -i redis
```

The only way I can start the redis server is by manually running:

```
# redis-server /etc/redis/default.conf
```

which starts the server without any problems.

I've tried to reinstall the redis package and tried to change the vendor from the "official" to "server:database" repository. None of these seem to be fixing the issue.

My `default.conf` file is pretty much the "default" template which only has these changed:

```
daemonize yes #default is no
bind 127.0.0.1 1.2.3.4 #default is 127.0.0.1
```

The service files:

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.target
[Unit]
Description=Redis target allowing to start/stop all redis@.service instances at once
```

---

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis@.service
[Unit]
Description=Redis
After=network.target
PartOf=redis.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=redis
Group=redis
PrivateTmp=true
PIDFile=/var/run/redis/%i.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/redis-server /etc/redis/%i.conf
Restart=on-failure

#ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --suppress-timestamps --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf
#ExecReload=/sbin/killproc -p /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid -HUP /usr/sbin/openvpn

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target redis.target
```

Any ideas what has changed from 13.2 to 42.1 and why has the service stopped working? Also I don't seem to recall how I previously had the redis listed in `chkconfig` - after the upgrade it's gone from there, although I'm not quite sure that's part of the problem.

Edit:
Here is the log file thanks to @Michael Hampton:

````
9042:signal-handler (1448036091) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 3.0.4 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in standalone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 9042
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

9042:M 20 Nov 18:14:51.090 # Server started, Redis version 3.0.4
9042:M 20 Nov 18:14:51.091 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
9042:M 20 Nov 18:14:51.091 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
9042:M 20 Nov 18:14:51.091 # User requested shutdown...
9042:M 20 Nov 18:14:51.091 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
9042:M 20 Nov 18:14:51.126 * DB saved on disk
9042:M 20 Nov 18:14:51.126 * Removing the pid file.
9042:M 20 Nov 18:14:51.126 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
````

I'm not sure why it decides to spontaneously just quit due to "user requested shutdown".

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing in the logs. Neither in `/var/log/messages` nor in `/var/log/redis/`. The redis log dir is completely empty. It only creates a log file if I run the start up command manually. Am I looking in the wrong place? If you'd like I could post the full redis config but it's rather long.

Comment: You're running systemd, so you probably want to go grovel around in its database of log data.

Answer (score 3):

This is a systemd unit which is capable of instantiating multiple copies of a server with different configurations.

To use it, specify the name of the instance you want to use. For instance, your existing configuration seems to have the name `default`:

```
systemctl enable redis@default
systemctl start redis@default
```

You will probably have to change the `/etc/redis/default.conf` so that it writes the `pidfile` in the location that systemd expects.

```
pidfile /var/run/redis/default.pid
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This pointed me to the right direction! Now the log file is being created. I've updated my answer with the log.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for a while I found out that need to comment out the `daemonize yes` or set it to `no`. The funny part is I had the same configuration on 13.2 and it worked without any problems.

Anyway hope this helps anybody.